# tablesorter incorrectly scrolls disabled buttons with sticky headers

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

I am seeing some strange behavior with tablesorter when I have sticky headers enabled and buttons in a column.  When the buttons are *enabled*, they correctly disappear "under" the header as I scroll the rows up.  However, when the buttons are *disabled*, they do not disappear "under" the header as the scroll up - instead, they appear above the header.  See the images for what I mean.  The first image shows the problem )buttons disabled) while the second image shows correct behavior (buttons enabled) (the header is the light blue with the "Action" text):

[image: tablesorter incorrect disabled button behavior]

Your help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

Table sort version is 2.18.3

Here is the table js and the css for both the enabled and disabled buttons:

```
    $('#tablesorter-ap-list').tablesorter({
        theme : 'blue',
        headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
        widgets    : ['zebra','columns', 'cssStickyHeaders', 'uitheme'],
        sortList     :[[0,0]],
        headers: {},
        widthFixed : true,
        widgetOptions: {
            cssStickyHeaders_offset        : 0,
            cssStickyHeaders_addCaption    : true,
            // jQuery selector or object to attach sticky header to
            cssStickyHeaders_attachTo      : null,
            cssStickyHeaders_filteredToTop : true,
            cssStickyHeaders_zIndex        : 10
        }
    });
```

Here is the css for an enabled button column (two buttons in this example):

```
<td>
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="/hs/bk/ae/986/cac:cac_top/" role="button">Edit</a>
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="/hs/bk/av/986/cac:cac_top/">View</a>
</td>
```

And here is the css for the disabled button case.  It's interesting to note that it does not matter if one or both buttons are disabled - as long as one is disabled, the incorrect scroll behavior is exhibited):

```
<td>
    <a type="button" disabled class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="/hs/bk/ae/954/cac:cac_top/" role="button">Edit</a>
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="/hs/bk/av/954/cac:cac_top/">View</a>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you share the css for the buttons... css for both the enabled & disabled state.

Comment: I think this is some kind of z-order problem with the sticky headers (not sure why this matters when buttons are enabled/disabled).  I say this because as the table scrolls underneath the sticky header, I can see a few pixels of the scrolled table just above the header (regardless of whether there are buttons involved or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's an issue with [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). When a button is disabled, Bootstrap applies an `opacity` to the button; this causes the stacking issue with the `thead` which uses a transform.

I found this solution which restores the opacity and changes the back & changes the background color ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/856bzzeL/715/)):

```
a.btn[disabled] {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0,128,0,0.3);
    border-color: rgba(0,128,0,0.3);
}
```

Comment: sorry for the delay - I will try the fix in my code tomorrow...

I tried your demo above (at the link you provided) and I noticed another, smaller nit that is there the same as on my tables: Just above the header bar is about a one or two pixel area between the bar and the bottom edge of the pane -- as you scroll, you will see a few pixels in this area changing as the table scrolls through that 1-2 pixel horizontal area.  It's not a huge deal but is it a bit distracting for users,

Comment: I apologize for this amateur second question but I have researched and not found anything helpful on the subject of table "flashing" at init.  I have reasonably large tables (say 100 rows, 15 cols) and when the page first shows, they show in a default color (brownish) and then when the page is initted, they flash (loudly) back to my blue theme.  I have tried many things to no avail.  Any thoughts/links would be appreciated. Since I know you are the ts guru, I figured you'd have some insight. Ideally, I'd like the table to not even show until it's ready to render.

Comment: What you're seeing is called a FOUC (Flash of unstyled content). If you want your table to have a blue theme applied on init, add a "tablesorter-blue" class name to the table. If you still want to hide the table, then I have to think of an alternative method.

Comment: Mottie: two thumbs up on both fixes!!  I had to do the css a bit differently and I decided I wanted a special class for this case so I did this: 'a.btn.disabled.tablesorter-btn-fix-success{...}'  and applied tablesorter-btn-fix-success class to the disabled buttons only.  Many thanks - the tablesorter-blue works great and meets all my needs.  Love the suggestive acronym ;)

Comment: LOL I didn't make it up... [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

Comment: Re: the stacking context, why does the header z-index not fix this?

Comment: Read the article I shared... and if I knew how to solve it, I would have posted it here.

Comment: Got it - thanks.  I assumed it was a ts problem - bad assumption.